# Override Object.length function

Tags: javascript

I want to override the `length` function:

```
function x_funct(){
     this.length = function(){
         console.log("hello");
        return 8;
    }
};

var x = new x_funct();
console.log(x.length);
```

When executed with node it prints `[Function]`. I was expecting to see `hello`.

Comment: Why what isn't allowed? That you ran it kind of implies it *is* allowed. Are you asking why your function you didn't call didn't get called?

Comment: `x.length` is indeed a function. Did you mean to call the function? `x.length()`

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what you mean. Do you expect to see the source code of the function? Do you expect the execute the function? Something else?

Comment: I want to override the length function, to include console.log("hello").

Comment: @lulbaiking Since you didn't edit the question I did it for you, but of course I'm not you so I can't assume I understood your needs. Please edit the question yourself if I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `.length` to be a function, not a value property. You can make a readonly property with `Object.defineProperty`

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', { get: function() { return val; } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that what you are showing, the function.

Functions are objects in Javascript, so if you try to print `x.length`, you print the function itself, not the result of it.

If you want to print the result, you should write `x.length()`